# Looping through attributes within Class instances?

Tags: python, class, instance

I am trying to simulate a baseball game to learn more about python and programming in general... I ran into an interesting learning point in programing... and was wondering if someone could explain this error...

```
import random 

rosterHome = []
rosterAway = []


class Player: 
    def __init__(self, number, battingAverage): 
        self.number = number 
        self.battingAverage = battingAverage

class Game: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.inning = 0 
        self.homeScore = 0 
        self.awayScore = 0 
        self.outs = 0 

    def createStats(): 
        for i in range(40): 
            stats = random.random() 
            x = Player(i, stats) 
            rosterHome.append(x) 
        for y in range(40): 
            stats = random.random() 
            y = Player(i, stats) 
            rosterAway.append(y) 
        
    def startGame(): 
        Game.createStats() 
        Game.inning = 0 
        Game.homeScore = 0 
        Game.awayScore = 0 
        Game.outs = 0
        Game.playInning() 
  
    def playInning():
        totalHits = 0 
        if Game.inning >= 10: 
            print('Game is Over')
            return 
        while Game.outs < 3: 
            for i in rosterHome:
                x = rosterHome[i] 
                if x.battingAverage > random.random(): 
                    totalHits += 1
                    player += 1
                    print('batter ', player, ' got a hit')
                else: 
                    Game.outs += 1
                    player += 1
                    print('batter ', player, ' got out')
                    print('there are ', Game.outs, ' outs.') 

Game.startGame()
```

x = rosterHome[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Player

Comment: When you do `for i in rosterHome:` `i` will be the actual item in `rosterHome` not an index. Each `i` will be a `Player` object which is why you get the error.

Comment: Awesome, that helped a lot. So I can remove the line x = rosterHome[i], but now it is not letting me i += 1 to move to the next instance of a Player stored in rosterHome... ideally, I would like to iterate over rosterHome (which is full of Players) to compare their batting average to a random number to dictate whether they get a hit or not...

Comment: If you're using a for loop you don't need to move to the next player manually. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ColeRagone so you want to iterate the list of players and stop when the out counter reaches 3 OR when there are no players left? That's a slightly different question

Comment: Yes, youre right... just ran it and saw that it moves the player by itself, but it doesn't seem to stop when self.outs > 3...?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**:
`List indices must be integers or slices`
The interpreter says "Hey, I see you're trying to access an item in a List by its index, but indices should be of type `integer`, however, you passed a value of type `Player`"

In Python and most programming languages, to reference an item in a List/Array, one way would be by index. Lists are zero-indexed, so the first item is of index 0, the second index 1, and so on.

Given an Array

```py
my_array = ["bread", "foo", "bar"]

my_array[0] # would give you "bread"
my_array[1] # would give you "foo"
my_array[2] # would give you "bar"
```

However in your case, if we trace back up from where the error occurred, right here:

```py
x = rosterHome[i]
```

You want to ask, what is the value of `i`? above this line is a for loop, and `i` represents each value in a list called `rosterHome`. So what the heck is in `rosterHome` anyways?

Moving up into your `createStats` method where you populated the `rosterHome` list, we see that you're pushing an instance of `Player` into the `rosterHome` list.

```py
x = Player(i, stats) 
rosterHome.append(x)
```

So rosterHome really isn't a list of numbers but instead a list of `Player` instances. You might want to review and try again, maybe accessing the number property of the Player object instead.

Comment: rosterHome is a list of Players representing the Home Team. I was trying to iterate over each player and compare their batting average to a random number to decide whether or not they get a hit, and if not, an out... when the out counter reaches 3, the inning would end. Associated with each Player is a batting average that I created using createStats()... by removing x = rosterHome[i] and using i.battingStats > random.random(), it helped that error, but now it iterates over the entire homeRoster and doesn't listen to the while outs < 3 argument... any help here?

Comment: You might have some other problems within your code still, for example, I see you're doing this player += 1, however you didn't define the `player` variable before referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because `rosterHome` is a list of instances of the `Player` class, so when you iterate on the list (`for i in rosterHome`) each element will be an instance of said class (`i` is a `Player`). If you want to access the number of each player you'll have to access the attribute `number` of your `Player` instances, but it seems like actually you want to find the player instance. This means, you don't even need to lookup the value in the table, just use the value of the for loop. I'll use a different naming of variables to improve readability:

```
while Game.outs < 3:
    for player in rosterHome:
        # x wanted to access a player, but we don't need to do that actually
        if player.battingAverage > random.random():
            # ...
        else:
            # ...
```

---

This part of the answer considers that you actually want to meet both  requirements (number of outs and iterate players once):

```py
player_index = 0
while Game.outs < 3 and player_index< len(rosterHome):
    player = rosterHome[player_index]
    if player.battingAverage > random.random():
        # ...
    else:
        # ...
if Game.outs == 3:
    # Reached 3 outs
else:
    # No players left and game outs < 3
```